# agree or disagree and prove : UA = UB then A=B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

agree or disagree and prove : union of A equal union of B then A equal to B .

Comment: $\bigcup\{\{1,2\}\}= \{1,2\}=\bigcup\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$, but $\{\{1,2\}\}\neq\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union of $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ is the same as union of $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,4\}$

But collections A={ {1,2} , $\{3,4\}\}$ and $B=   \{\{1,3\} , \{2,4\}\}$ are not the same.